# Img into Flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

Hi I'm bloody noob at HTML/CSS and also new on this site, so excuse me if I'm not the best right away.

I've created a Box and wanted to add an img in the center(but on the top side like this https://prnt.sc/ugx0q4)

But all I can do is this
https://prnt.sc/ugx1in

Here is my code:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    
    <div class="flex-column">
        
        <div class="flex-box1">FAHRPLAN- UND <br> PREISANKUNFT <img src="../Aufgabe1new/img/button.png" class="btn"></br></div>
        <div class="flex-box1">ABFAHRTEN</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-column">
        <div class="flex-box2">STÖRUNGEN</div>
        <div class="flex-box2">FAHRPLANER-APP</div>
    </div>

    <div class="extra-big">
        <div class="flex-big">Direkt zum passenden Ticket</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-column">
        <div class="flex-box3">BURGERBUS</div>
        <div class="flex-box3"> PARK + RIDE</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-column">
        <div class="flex-box4">VBN BEI NACHT</div>
        <div class="flex-box4">BARRIEREFREIHEIT</div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I have more than one box. I have like 9 and all 8 of them need this icon just like the first one.

Here is the css part:

```
    .flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
}


.flex-box1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 142px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: rgb(215, 84, 87);

    
}
.flex-box2{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: rgb(215, 84, 87);



}

.flex-box3{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: rgb(215, 84, 87);


}
.flex-box4{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: rgb(215, 84, 87);



}
.flex-big{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0.5em;  
    padding-bottom: 335px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(215, 84, 87);
    
}

.flex-column{
    margin: 5px;
    
}
```

Its probably pretty messed up I'm very sorry and i just entered the stack overflow world. Please be kind.

edit: it looks like this right now: https://prnt.sc/ugxa3k

Comment: why not put the image before the text if you want the image on top?  otherwise wrap the text and use flex direction column reverse on the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is to make the image come before the text

```
<div class="flex-container">

        <div class="flex-column">
            
            <div class="flex-box1">
                <div class="flex-img">
                <img src="../Aufgabe1new/img/button.png" class="btn"> <!--Your image in its own div before the text-->
            </div>
            <p>
                FAHRPLAN- UND <br> PREISANKUNFT 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-box1">ABFAHRTEN</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="flex-column">
            <div class="flex-box2">STÖRUNGEN</div>
            <div class="flex-box2">FAHRPLANER-APP</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="extra-big">
            <div class="flex-big">Direkt zum passenden Ticket</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="flex-column">
            <div class="flex-box3">BURGERBUS</div>
            <div class="flex-box3"> PARK + RIDE</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="flex-column">
            <div class="flex-box4">VBN BEI NACHT</div>
            <div class="flex-box4">BARRIEREFREIHEIT</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: in the first flex-box1, i created another div to hold the image, then paragraph to hold the text

Comment: Thanks @Amospikins ! Now I need somehow get it to the top/center